# SaaS webapp to sell event tickets (about 20 people expected)

Tags: web-apps, ecommerce, saas

I am looking for a event management software to sell tickets that take me as cheaply as possible which is the easiest to use that is rather in the spirit of the entertainment world. I would like it to allow me also a good follow-up of the events and which allows me to do a little marketing, cluster by customers...

I largely heard about Eventbrite and Ticket tailor but I'm really new to this world and was wondering if they were alternatives what would be the perfect fit.

It's for swing dancing parties in London where I'm waiting for around 20 people to come. I thought about selling tickets online and cash at the party as well.

Comment: What country are you in? What are the ways the company could send you the money? (bank transfer? other?)

Comment: Also, is it OK to require that all customers are required to have a credit card, or do you require other forms of payment such as convenience store payment?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I added some details
I didn't know what convenience store are. I tried to Google it but I'm still not sure

Comment: It means you don't pay on the Internet, instead you have like 24 hours to go to a nearby partner shop and give them the cash.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Oh, no ! It sounds like a good idea though !
To be honest I chose tickettailor but I'm not sure they offer this option.
Otherwise I will add this option to the post on [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/events/616283885438140/) and [tickettailor](https://www.tickettailor.com/events/londonsoirerockparties/180249#). But it wouldn't make it really pro, isn't it ?
I'm so new to entrepreneurship.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul But then I need to post another question for a software that generates hand-to-hand tickets ?

Comment: If you also need software to generate hand-to-hand tickets that might be better as a separate question indeed, unless you want some integration between the two.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the founder of Ticket Tailor and came across your question.

We usually work out much cheaper than Eventbrite due to the fact that we don't take a cut on the ticket sale and we allow you to use stripe for payment processing who have low payment processing fees. You can see details of our pricing here: https://www.tickettailor.com/pricing

Whilst Ticket Tailor doesn't offer the ability to do marketing emails, we do offer a MailChimp integration. This means anyone who buys tickets to your events can be automatically synchronised to a list of contacts on MailChimp.